# Why does overwriting datetime.datetime in function a affect the execution of function b?

Tags: python, unit-testing, scope, patch

I'm currently writing an article about patching for unit testing in Python and I got confused why the following works. When I execute `pytest` in that directory, the test succeeds although my system time is not in 1990.

I thought that the `datetime.datetime = NewDate` would only have an effect within the `test_example.py`. I think I need a better understanding of where Python stores the name / pointers to the imported modules. Can somebody please explain this?

### example.py

```py
# Core Library modules
import datetime


def generate_filename():
    return f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}.png"
```

### test_example.py

```py
# Core Library modules
import datetime
from unittest import mock

# First party modules
from mock_example import generate_filename


class NewDate(datetime.datetime):
    @classmethod
    def now(cls):
        return cls(1990, 4, 28)


def test_generate_filename():
    datetime.datetime = NewDate
    assert generate_filename() == "1990-04-28.png"
```

Comment: This behavior is why you don't just replace an object by a fake object in a test, but use `mock.patch` or similar that reverts the patching as soon as you leave the scope.

Answer (score 1):

On the line where you import the `from mock_example import generate_filename`, the `import datetime` is executed, and therefore the value of `datetime.datetime` gets overwritten on `datetime.datetime = NewDate` since it get executed after the import. All modifications to any global variable (including imports) that happens on the same program affects everywhere in the program no matter they are in different files.

You are literally accessing the same 'variable' on both files. This won't happen if you import it like `from datetime import datetime` (more info about this on the @Vishal Singh [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62647576/10798938))

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you patch the `datetime.datetime` module inside `test_generate_filename` there are 2 kinds of imports that you need to be mindful of

1. `import a` or `import a.b` (and using it like `a.method` or `a.b.method`)
2. `from a import b` ( this will leave unpatched reference of b if imported before calling `test_generate_filename` and if used in that module will give you unpatched content)

In your case, you are importing it like `import datetime` so there are no old references and you've patched the module so any future use of `datetime.datetime.now()` in any file would return the patched content i.e 90's date.

If you try importing datetime like `from datetime import datetime` in your `example.py` file then your  assertion will Fail.